# Updating a table using a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-update

As you can see what I want to do is:

[1] grab the **author_id** of a record that matches `$toggled` in table **forum_qa**

[2] update **reputation** in  **user_profiles** where **user_id** matches **author_id**

```
    UPDATE  user_profiles

    (SELECT forum_qa_author_id AS author_id
    FROM    forum_qa
    WHERE   forum_qa_id = $toggled) AS f

    SET     user_profiles.reputation = user_profiles.reputation - 15
    WHERE   user_profiles.user_id = f.author_id
```

This is giving me a 1064 syntax error at `(SELECT...`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE  user_profiles
SET     user_profiles.reputation = user_profiles.reputation - 15
WHERE   user_profiles.user_id = (SELECT forum_qa_author_id AS author_id
FROM    forum_qa
WHERE   forum_qa_id = $toggled)
```

Answer (score 0):

The subquery has to come after the "SET" . In this case it might not necessarily need a sub query...

try...

```
UPDATE user_profiles
   SET user_profiles.reputation = user_profiles.reputation - 15
  FROM user_profiles
  JOIN forum_qa f ON user_profiles.user_id = f.author_id
   AND forum_qa_id = $toggled
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UDPATE up set reputation = reputation - 15 
FROM user_profiles up inner join forum_qa fq on (up.user_id = fq.forum_qa_id) 
WHERE forum_qa_id = $toggled
```

I just realised that you are using MySQL. This is for MS SQL, I'm not sure if you can use it exactly the same way in MySQL but hopefully it's a little bit of help..